# USB hub often disconnects entirely when transferring data

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply

I have a standard non-powered 4-port USB hub connected to a Surface Pro 4.

I have 3 devices plugged into the hub:

1. Transmitter for keyboard/mouse
2. Powered 3tb HDD
3. Powered 10tb HDD

Every so often, on a fairly regular basis, the hub vanishes from Windows. The hard drives disappear from Explorer and the mouse/keyboard stops working.

15 seconds later it reconnects and everything appears again. Sometimes it happens once a day, sometimes it happens 10 times within the hour. It is seemingly random.

I'm sure this is going to kill my hard drives, so I've been trying everything I can find online to solve the issue.

Would a powered hub help in this situation or is it irrelevant since both hard drives are fully powered with their own supply?

Is there a limit on data transfer through a single USB port? It often happens when I'm copying multiple files from one drive to the other using robocopy - but it also happens when both drives are idle.

I've never had this issue when either of the drives are connected directly to the Surface, but as it only has a single USB port I'm not able to work this way.

I have disabled the option in device manager that allows Windows to turn off devices to save power.

Comment: Try a powered USB Hub. The collection of devices is very likely drawing too much current (power) from the Surface USB port causing disconnection.

Comment: I was under the impression that the powered HDDs took no power from the USB hub, since they each have their own power supply. Do they actually still draw some power from the hub?

Comment: There might be some small draw, then traffic, then two drives, and then the third device. I am suggesting you try a powered hub. I have one on my desktop for a monitor connection, USB and a couple of other devices and I do not get any interruption.

Comment: What kind of IC do you have inside your hub? Does the disconnect ever happen when only one drive is connected and data are transferred?

Comment: Thanks John I'll try a powered hub.

Comment: Ale..chenski what do you mean by IC? I'm unable to test with one drive at the moment as I'm currently backing up a lot of files between the drives, but will check as soon as it finalises.

Comment: I mean the brand and particular integrated circuit (IC) inside your hub. You can check it by using either Device Manager, or USBTreeView, by finding its Product ID and Vendor ID.

Comment: A powered hub has not helped. Not completely, at least. One of the drives dissapears on occasion, but the other does not. Also the transmitter for the mouse and keyboard, which initially worked in all ports, suddenly stopped and now only works in one port. I can't seriously be having this much bad luck with individual products. Something deeper must be going on.

Comment: Try to disable USB U1/U2 Link power management, it is tricky however https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108194-add-usb-3-link-power-management-power-options-windows.html